# WiX Custom Action to check firewall status causes installer to fail

Tags: c#, wix

I have implemented a WiX Custom Action in C# to check whether the Windows firewall is on or off.

I tested the code with a C# console application and it worked without problems.

However, when I use the code in a WiX Custom Action it causes the installer to fail at run-time, with the following error in the msiexec error log:

DEBUG: Error 2755:  Server returned unexpected error 1622 attempting to
nstall package MyInstaller.msi.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package.
This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2755.
The arguments are: 1622, MyInstaller.msi,

Action ended 11:26:30: ExecuteAction. Return value 3.
Action 11:26:30: FatalError. 
Action start 11:26:30: FatalError.
Action 11:26:30: FatalError. Dialog created
Action ended 11:26:31: FatalError. Return value 2.
Action ended 11:26:31: INSTALL. Return value 3.

```
Type NetFwMgrType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwMgr", true);

INetFwMgr fwMgr = Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType) as INetFwMgr;

bool Firewallenabled = fwMgr.LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.FirewallEnabled;

MessageBox.Show("Firewall enabled: " + Firewallenabled.ToString());
```

In my WiX XML file the CA is like this:

```
  <CustomAction Id="CheckWindowsFirewallId"
  BinaryKey="CustomActions.dll"
  DllEntry="CheckWindowsFirewall"  Execute="deferred"  Impersonate="no" Return="check"/>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
<Custom Action="CheckWindowsFirewallId" After="InstallInitialize">NOT Installed</Custom>
```

I am using Visual Studio 2005, Windows XP, WiX version 3.6.1321.0

I am logged in as admininstrator.

I know exactly which line causes in the problem.

If I comment out the line with "Activator.CreateInstance(NetFwMgrType)" the error does not occur.

I have tried several different combinations of 'deferred' and 'impersonate' with no success.

If I can't get it to work I will try the WiX Firewall Extension instead, but it would be great if someone has an idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: Whatever the reason of the problem is, I would still recommend you to try to accomplish your goal with WiX Firewall extension. It was tested better than your own CA, I suspect ;-) and it is always better to rely on something more or less standard, than inventing your own wheel. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't enough information to know for sure. However, my magic eight ball guesses that the assembly your trying to activate a class out of isn't available. The best thing would be to get a debugger on the code and look at the exception. If you're having trouble doing that, catching the exception and writing it to the log file might be useful as well.

I also agree with Yan's comment above. I'd recommend using the built in support for Firewalls in WiX instead of writing your own code if possible.